# Change friend request accepted email in buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I try to change the text in the email from "{{username}} accepted your friend request." to "{{username}} accepted your invitation."

I tried via .po file transaltion like below in "wp-content/languages/plugins/buddypress-en_US.po" file.

```
#. translators: do not remove {} brackets or translate its contents.
#: bp-core/bp-core-functions.php:3197
msgid ""
"<a href=\"{{{friendship.url}}}\">{{friend.name}}</a> accepted your friend "
"request."
msgstr "<a href=\"{{{friendship.url}}}\">{{friend.name}}</a> accepted your invitation."
```

But I couldn't get the proper result (email with changed text), could anyone tell any other way to do this, even via by any hook or filter, it will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BuddyPress 2.5+ all emails that are sent can be edited in wp-admin area. Check the screenshot below. Just go to that email and change its subject and content as you wish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the release of BuddyPress 2.5.0, site administrators can easily edit the contents of email notifications. These notifications use “tokens,” which are generic placeholders that are replaced with specific data when a single message is generated and sent. Check this link

https://codex.buddypress.org/emails/email-tokens/